# What is correct: "at Kent Gliding Club" or "in Kent Gliding Club"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, british-english

I want to give a description of my youtube video (I gave it actually, but I am not sure if it is correct). What is the proper form?

> 2000ft aerotow *at* Kent Gliding Club.

or

> 2000ft aerotow *in* Kent Gliding Club.

Related video [here](https://youtu.be/6ktmoJZkddA).

I asked this question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/605929/what-is-correct-at-kent-gliging-club-or-in-kent-gliding-club), but unfortunately, it was closed before I got any advice.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided the whole sentence or paragraph for context, rather than just a snippet. However since the aerotow is, presumably, a service offered at the club you could say "2000ft aerotow **by** the Kent Gliding Club"

Comment: It is not the service. I just want to show that my flight was concluded in (at) Kent Gliding Club. On other club videos people use in (at) so I cant figure what is the correct form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At" seems the better of the two options.  The aerotow isn't a member of the club, so can't be "in" the club.  But the club has a base and you are giving the location of the flight so "at" seems possible.

Potential alternative is "with the Kent gliding club" in the sense that you are with your clubmates who are providing the tow.

Comment: Thank you - I have changed my descriptions. `"aerotow"` is a gliding slang (but also used officially as a "launch method")